# Pytest HTML report: how to get the name of the report file?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I am using pytest with [pytest-html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-html/) module to generate an HTML test report.

In the tear-down stage I automatically open the generated HTML report in the browser with `webbrowser.open('file:///path_to_report.html')` — this works fine, but I am running the test with different arguments and for each set of arguments I am setting a different report file via command line arguments:

```
pytest -v mytest.py::TestClassName --html=report_localhost.html
```

My tear-down code looks like this:

```python
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def config(request):
    claz = request.cls
    claz.host = request.config.getoption("--host", default=HOST_DEFAULT)
    ...

    def teardown_env():
        print('destroying test harness')
        webbrowser.open("file:///path_to_report_localhost.html")

    request.addfinalizer(teardown_env)

    return "prepare_env"
```

The question is how to access the report file name from the tear-down hook in the test so that instead of hard-coding it I can use whatever path was passed in as command line argument, i.e. `--html=report_for_host_xyz.html`?

## ⚠️ Update

Using a class-scoped fixture for displaying the generated HTML is not the correct approach because `pytest-html` hooks the report generation into the session finalizer scope which means that by the time the class finalizer is called the report is still not generated and you might need to refresh the browser page to actually see the report. And if it *seems* to work it's only because the browser window might take some extra seconds to open which might allow the report generation to finish by the time the file is loaded in the browser.

The correct way to do it is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034116/191246) and boils down to using the [`pytest_unconfigure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_unconfigure) hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a breakpoint in the fixture, and look into `request.config.option` object — this is where pytest puts all the argparsed's keys.

The one that you look for is `request.config.option.htmlpath`.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def config(request):
    claz = request.cls
    claz.host = request.config.getoption("--host", default=HOST_DEFAULT)

    yield 100   # a value of the fixture for the tests

    print('destroying test harness')
    webbrowser.open("file:///{}".format(request.config.option.htmlpath))
```

Or you can do the same as for the `--host` key:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def config(request):
    claz = request.cls
    claz.host = request.config.getoption("--host", default=HOST_DEFAULT)

    yield 100   # a value of the fixture for the tests

    print('destroying test harness')
    webbrowser.open("file:///{}".format(request.config.getoption("--html")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Since I'm only passing a relative path on the command line (`--html=report_localhost.html`) I had to prepend the absolute folder: `html_report_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), request.config.option.htmlpath); webbrowser.open("file://{path}".format(path=html_report_path))`

Comment: @ccpizza In that case, you probably want `os.path.join(request.config.invocation_dir, filename)`. In rare cases, `os.path.join(request.config.rootdir, filename)`. But root dir is a common parent of all found tests, while the invocation dir is from where you started the pytest process. Consider: `cd ~/proj; pytest ./some/dir1/ ./some/dir2/t.py` — the invocation dir will be `~/proj`, but the rootdir will be `~/proj/some`.

Comment: that's so much cleaner! Much appreciated! 

Comment: UPD: Oops. I'm slightly wrong. The root dir is where pytest detects the root of the project, usually by the presence of `setup.py`, `setup.cfg`, `pytest.cfg` and similar files. In case they are not found, then it is the invocation dir. In case the tests are above the invocation dir, then the most common parent dir. So, you can use `os.path.join(request.config.rootdir, filename)` in case you want the path to be relative to the project root dir. But the invocation (aka current) dir as the base dir is still more natural and expected by the users.

Comment: My setup is pretty simple, so `invocation_dir` and `rootdir` point to the same path. But it's good to know the difference between the two. Btw, they both return `LocalPath` objects and not strings, and therefore should be used as `request.config.rootdir.strpath`.