# Pytest: how to display generated report after test run?

Tags: python, report, pytest, pytest-html

I am using pytest in combination with the [pytest-html](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html) plugin which generates an HTML report after the test has run.

I am using an auto-wired session fixture to automatically open the generated HTML report in a browser:

```python
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def session_wrapper(request):
    print('Session wrapper init...')
    yield

    # open report in browser on Mac or Windows, skip headless boxes
    if platform.system() in ['Darwin', 'Windows']:
        html_report_path = os.path.join(request.config.invocation_dir.strpath, request.config.option.htmlpath)
        open_url_in_browser("file://%s" %html_report_path)
```

The code above works, but not consistently, because sometimes the browser attempts to load the file before it is created which results in a file not found error, and requires a manual browser refresh in order for the report to be shown.

My understanding is that `scope="session"` is the widest available scope, and my assumption was that pytest-html should finish generating the report before the end of the session, but apparently that is not the case.

The question is: what would be the correct way to hook the browser report auto-launch code? Could it be that `pytest-html` is also hooking into the session finalizer scope? In that case how to make sure that the HTML file is open in the browser only after the file has been created?

Comment: Why do you want to do this inside the testing framework, instead of outside?

Comment: @StephenRauch: because I would like to avoid doing it explicitly in every script where `pytest` is called.

Answer (score 3):

In your `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    config._htmlfile = config._html.logfile


@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    file = session.config._htmlfile
    # invoke the file opening in external tool
    os.system('open ' + file)
```

Notes:

- `pytest-html` writes the report in `pytest_sessionfinish` hook, so you will need a custom sessionfinish hook. Mark it with `trylast=True` to ensure your hook impl runs after `pytest-html`'s one.
- `config.option.htmlpath` is what is passed via `--html-path` command line argument; `config._html.logfile` is what `pytest-html` actually uses as file name. It's accessible after `pytest-html`'s configure hook finishes, so I used `trylast=True` one more time.

Answer (score 2):

As helpfully hinted by [massimo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52033704/191246), a possible solution is to use a [hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_unconfigure), specifically [`pytest_unconfigure`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_unconfigure) which can be placed in `conftest.py` so that it is available for all tests.

```python
def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    if platform.system() in ['Darwin', 'Windows']:
        html_report_path = os.path.join(config.invocation_dir.strpath, config.option.htmlpath)
        open_url_in_browser("file://%s" % html_report_path)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's too soon to open the file in unconfigure hook. Doublecheck you're not just opening a previously generated report. E.g. `rm myreport.html && pytest --html=myreport.html`.

Comment: @hoefling: in fact, debugging shows that `pytest_unconfigure` runs _**after**_  `pytest_sessionfinish` with `trylast=True`.

Comment: You're right, tested it myself via `pytest --debug`. Cool, always thought the `unconfigure` is called before `sessionfinish` for some reasons. Your answer is thus perfectly valid, disregard my comment above!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using fixtures you may try using [hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#hooks).

In the past I did something interesting with them, unfortunately I don't remember if there's called at the very end of the run but probably yes

Comment: that's exactly what I was thinking of: but the question is which hook would be the most appropriate? `pytest_report_collectionfinish`? I see that pytest-html hooks into `pytest_sessionfinish`, so how would I hook to something after that?

Comment: collection_finish should be called ad the end of collection not after the execution. As I said I have no time now to check the doc, maybe later